# Python coredumps when installing python packages with pip3 locally instead as root

Tags: python, pip

I installed python packages with pip3 (conan and conan_package_tools) under a regular user account.
If I then run a build the python process crashes with a coredump.

If I instead install the python packages globally as user root (with sudo pip3) then everything works as it should.

My suspicion is, that it puts files under .local/lib/python3.6 but resolves them from the system and that leads to the crash. Setting PYTHONPATH to .local/lib/python3.6 did unfortunately not help.

Any ideas what the reason could be or how to debug this further? All of this is run in a minimal Ubuntu 18.04 Docker environment.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  What do you mean by "under my user account"?  You mentioned you're working in a Docker container, which runs as root by default anyways.

Comment: Just a regular user account inside the docker container instead of root (added with adduser).